# $q resolve function not triggering then

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, angular-promise

I thought I was using the [AngularJS $q](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q) interface correctly. But the function I'm passing to the `then` callback is never being executed. And I am calling `resolve` in the function which is wrapped by `$q`. I've verified that `resolve()` is being called, yet it seems this is not the same function which is chained with `.then()`:

```
$q(function(resolve, reject) {
  resolve();
  reject();
  console.log("This happens");  //This shows that resolve() is being called
}).then(function() {
  console.log("This doesn't");  //Yet this never gets executed
}).catch(function() {
  console.log("This also doesn't happen");
});
```

The output is:

```
This happens
```

What am I doing wrong?

My environment is a KarmaJS unit test with mocha and sinon-chai.

Comment: can you  add a rejection and see if that fires and why?

Comment: @Dayan Moreno Leon: Did so and updated the question. The `catch` function also isn't happening.

Comment: yes a missed the part where this was a test, Remco is right you need to trigger angulars digest cycle using either $apply  or $digest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call `$rootScope.$apply()`.

```
$q(function(resolve, reject) {
  resolve();
  console.log("This happens");  //This shows that resolve() is being called
}).then(function() {
  console.log("This too!");
});
$rootScope.$apply();
```